# iTunes: "Your account was changed while you were editing your account information."

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, apple-id

I logged into the iTunes store via Settings on a new iPhone 5s, and it automatically went to the "confirm your payment information" page.

I confirmed my method of payment (none), and it came back with an error, letting me know that:

> Your account was changed while you were editing your account info. We were unable to save the changes. Please try again later.

I was currently logged into the Manage my Apple ID page when this error occurred (but was not actively editing anything), and once I logged out, I was able to confirm my payment method with no issue.

I was also able to log into the iTunes store on my Macbook and confirm the payment information with zero issue, but as far as I remember I was not logged in into the manage my Apple ID page.

Has anyone experienced this before? Does being logged into the manage my Apple ID page seem like a likely culprit for the error message I received?

Answer (score 1):

I could see a race condition causing this briefly, but if you get this error for more than 15 minutes, I would get in queue with Apple support:

- http://www.apple.com/support/ios/contact/
- http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus

Unless there is an outage, you'll likely need someone to assist you on the sever side to resolve these errors.